# SQL Server : self join - retrieve records matching the where clause as well as when no records in alias table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below:

[image]

Query:

```
select t1.* 
from TABLE2 as t1 
left join TABLE2 as t2 on t1.itemcode = t2.itemcode 
                       and t1.warehouseid = '576' 
                       and t1.flag = 'Y' 
                       and t2.warehouseid = '276' 
                       and t2.flag = 'Y';
```

I have the above query and understand this is not perfect.

For an itemcode, if these conditions are met (t1.warehouseid='576' and t1.flag='Y' and t2.warehouseid='276' and t2.flag='Y') I want to retrieve that from t1.

Also, If there is no entry for an itemcode in t2 (Ex: 456 is not available for warehouseid 276), that also I want to retrieve from t1.

Expecting the following output,

```
 123        576     Y
 456        576     Y
```

What is the correct query for this?

**Edit:** 
To make the post more clear,

Warehouse id 576 is the main element.

For an itemcode, present in both warehouse id (576 , 276) with the flags being same ('Y') , I want to retrieve.

And If the itemcode is not in the other warehouse (276), that also I want to retrieve

For an itemcode, present in both warehouse id (576 , 276) with different flags ('Y' , 'N') , I don't want that.

Comment: so basically for whatever condition, you want from `t1` ?

Comment: @Squirrel For an itemcode, present in both warehouse id (576 , 276) with different flags, I don't want that. If the flags are same, I want to retrieve. And If the itemcode is not in the other warehouse that also I want to retrieve. Hope I have made this clear.

Comment: you have to provide more examples. your OP is quite confusing

Comment: This is confusing that you are adding conditions "and t1.warehouseid = '576'" and also expecting 123 and 456 from the same column as output.

Comment: @mkRabbani My query is not perfect, Squirrel's query is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interpret directly from your 2 conditions in `WHERE` clause

```
select  *
from    TABLE2  t
where   warehouseid = 576
and (
        exists   -- condition 1
        (
            select  *
            from    TABLE2 x
            where   x.itemcode  = t.itemcode
            and x.warehouseid   = 276
            and x.flag      = 'Y'
        )
    or  not exists -- condition 2
        (
            select  *
            from    TABLE2 x
            where   x.itemcode  = t.itemcode
            and x.warehouseid   = 276
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you

```
    select t1.* from TABLE2 as t1 
     left join TABLE2 as t2 
     on t1.itemcode=t2.itemcode and t2.warehouseid='276' and t2.flag='Y';
where
     t1.warehouseid='576' and t1.flag='Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach using row_number()

```
    with cte as
    (select t1.*,
    row_number() over(partition by itemcode order by warehouseid desc
                     ) rn
                from TABLE2 t1
    where not exists ( select 1 from TABLE2 t2 where t1.itemcode=t2.itemcode
                                                    and t2.flag='N'
                     ) and t1.warehouseid=576
   ) select * from cte where rn=1
```